# how to negate boolean in struts2 tag?

Tags: struts2, ognl

In a struts2 tag, the "!" negation operator doesn't seem to apply within Struts2. What am I doing wrong?

```
<s:if test="!%{true}">
    you should NOT see this
</s:if>
```

Comment: You don't need the Struts2 evaluation syntax. `test="!true"` ought to do it.

Comment: !true == false ,then why you are using !true.boolean type allows only true or false.

Answer (score 1):

You've put the `!` outside of the OGNL expression:

```
<s:if test="%{!true}">
```

While the `%{}` is optional in this case, some will argue that it should always be used to make the OGNL evaluation explicit. I tend to agree with that, although for simple use-cases I don't always bother.